# Elm how to update head of list

Tags: elm, cons, cdr

I am trying to program small time tracking application, where I write what I do, and it just logs it.

I successfully implemented adding entries to log, but now, I want to update last log entry with duration (for example when I started programming at 00:01, now it is 00:20 and I starting to write question on SO, so when I add that log entry to list, I want head of the list to have duration of 19 minutes, so I know how much time I spent programming).

I try to do it with this code:

```
addEntry: Model -> List LogEntry
addEntry model =
    let
        newEntry = { -- this is what we add
            text = model.currentText,
            timestamp = model.now,
            duration = Nothing
        }
        lastEntry =
            List.head model.log
    in
       case lastEntry of
           Nothing ->
                [newEntry] -- when the list was empty - create it with one element
           Just le -> -- when not empty
                newEntry :: {le | duration = newEntry.timestamp - le.timestamp } :: List.tail model.log
 -- - add new element, modified head and tail
```

The problem is that `List.tail model.log` is `Maybe List LogEntry`, and I want it to be `Just List LogEntry`. And it could only be `Just List LogEntry` there, because head is also `Just LogEntry`.

What to do there? Nest another one `case` and mark one branch as unaccessible? Is there some pattern how to do this? Or function like `List a -> Maybe (a, List a)`, that returns head and tail in the same `Maybe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pattern matching on lists (a list may be the empty list or a cons of head and tail):

```
let newEntry = {
  text = model.currentText,
  timestamp = model.now,
  duration = Nothing
}
in case model.log of
  [] -> [newEntry]
  le :: log -> 
    let le' = { le | duration = newEntry.timestamp - le.timestamp }
    in newEntry :: le' :: log
```

Comment: Great. Only duration wants to be `Just  (newEntry.timestamp - le.timestamp)`, because it is `Maybe`.